# Could you explain Methods about protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter hw)

Tags: c#, asp.net, render, htmltextwriter

i have some curiosities about Method name is Render.

There are some code examples about printing Page Index Number,

```
[Paging.cs source]
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter hw)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tr>");
        sb.Append("<td width=\"18\" align=\"center\" valign=\"bottom\"><a onfocus=\"blur();\" 
        class=\"pager\" href=\"javascript:" 
        + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, i.ToString()) + "\">
        <span style=\"width:18px;height:15px;cursor:hand;\">" + i + "</span></a></td>");
        sb.Append("</table>");
        hw.Write(sb.ToString());
    }

[default.aspx source]
<%@ Register Assembly="Control" Namespace="Control" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<cc1:Paging ID="pg_Addr" runat="server" OnPageChanged="pg_Addr_PageChanged" />
```

Could you explain easily that Methods

> 1. protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter hw) and
> 2. Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference

already searching MSDN and contents
I was supposed to understand, but I can't be sure.

are these methods just to using for Html Tag in behind code?

and i want to know about work procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HtmlTextWriter` is used to render HTML to ASP.Net web pages. This class encapsulates the output stream for writing content (HTML) to web page and provides many helper methods that simplify HTML writing.

`Render` method send HTML in response to a web request and generate content for an ASP.NET page.

In your snippet, your `Render` method is creating a HTML `Table`, writing it to `HtmlTextWriter`, which in turn will prepare the contents to be rendered on client browser.

---

`Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference`, returns a string that can be used in a client event to cause postback to the server.

In first argument it takes the server control that processes the postback on the server. It returns a string, which can be treated as script on the client that initiates the postback.

More on `GetPostBackEventReference` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have one more question.which one is calling  method of Render when web page is onload?   tag's name of <%@Register> or <cc1:Paging> ?

Comment: @Popcorn - The render method is called by the asp.net framework automatically. It doesnt have to be called explicitly.

Comment: I understand exactly! Thank you  :)